# Terminal pager: How to display a list in columns?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm sure it's very simple, but I can't remember how to tell a terminal pager (more/less/pg/most) to display a long list in columns.

Since my input is just a list of short elements, displaying it the same way `ls` does it by default would save me needless scrolling and precious screen real estate.

bad:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
```

good:

```
aaa ddd ggg
bbb eee hhh
ccc fff iii
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `column`.

Example:

```
ls -1 | column -c 100
```

This will format the output of `ls -1` (one entry per line) to fit as many columns of equal size as possible in rows that are 100 character wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste) to join lines from stdin:

```
paste - - - < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Daniel Beck's answer:

```
$ echo {a..c}{a..c}{a..c}| tr \  \\n | column | sed 's/\t/ /g' | $PAGER
aaa aba aca baa bba bca caa cba cca
aab abb acb bab bbb bcb cab cbb ccb
aac abc acc bac bbc bcc cac cbc ccc
```

The key is to make the output more compact by substituting tabs with spaces.